# What are the different parts of a zester called?

Tags: equipment, language

Earlier I was trying to describe which part of a zester to use and realized I have no idea what the different parts are called. I fell back on google, and was surprised to find nothing, there are plenty of zesters for sale, and plenty of people incorrectly calling microplane graters zesters but no terminology.

What are these parts of a zester called?

[image: Zester Parts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#1 is the zester.
#2 is called a channel knife, and is used to create a wider strip of zest for garnish.

Comment: # Headers made me smile ;-)

Comment: not exactly sure how that happened...thanks for the edit

Comment: a hashtag [US Pound] at the head of a line will give it "Big Header" status. You can mask them with a backslash.

Comment: So you're saying the reason I couldn't find what a zester was called, was because it's called a zester? I wish I could put a facepalm emoji in my comment!

Comment: You mean like this? ‍♂️ ;)